# How to create more random rows for a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

Suppose I have a Pandas Dataframe, with only one row, which looks something like this:-

```
      Column1 Column2 ...... Column n
Row 1 0.123  0.234.          0.156
```

Now, for instance, I want to generate 10 more rows for this, one way is to just duplicate this row 10 times. But, I want it to be coherent Mathematically and logical, such that the 10 more rows generated follow the normal distribution for example (though the problem is there is only 1 row), but do not want all rows to be the same. Is there any suitable way to generate more random rows based on this single row, such that the rows are not just plain duplicates?

Comment: shuffle the  order of the values 10 different ways?

Comment: You could generate a normal random noise and add to that row.

Comment: In what way do you want the new rows to be the same as row 1?  What attribute will the new rows inherit?

Comment: Have you looked at `numpy.random`? [(doc)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html)

Comment: @piRSquared the main aspect I want to target in this case is generating 10 more rows, such that for example, 5 of them have a random value subtracted from the Row 1 instances, and the other 5 have a random value added to the Row 1 instances. As there is no scope of inheriting the mean (as Column1-Column n are all different parameters), I want to be able to generate more rows which are very similar to the Row1, but not exact duplicates for that matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this will take your df, get the mean and standard deviation of row first row, and append as many rows as you want with numbers from a normal distribution. change the range to add more.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(df) 

standev = df.std(axis=1)
rowmean = df.mean(axis=1)

standev = standev[0]
rowmean = rowmean[0]
ncolumns = len(df.columns)

rows = []

for i in range(10):
    noise = np.random.normal(rowmean , standev , ncolumns)
    df.loc[len(df)]=noise
```